# Using iTextSharp to get y co-ordinates of text box?

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I'm using `iTextSharp` to return the text from a page in a PDF document,
using this :

```
var locationTextExtractionStrategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
string textFromPage = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, i + 1, locationTextExtractionStrategy);
```

I understand from [previous questions here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519945/x-and-y-coordinate-of-text-using-itextsharp) that I need to access

```
renderInfo.GetBaseline().GetStartPoint();
```

But I don't understand how to call that method from `LocationTextExtractionStrategy()`

Comment: You don't.  Here's an answer that should point you in the right direction: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7096093/itextsharp-getfieldpositions-to-setsimplecolumn)

Comment: You don't. If you search an AcroForm text field position, follow @safetyOtter's link. Otherwise you have to create your own extraction strategy and in its `renderText` method you can access the `TextRenderInfo renderInfo`. Your strategy of course can be derived from an existing strategy or a copy of one with some changes. Cf. e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13719947/1729265) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15086367/1729265).

Comment: I've tried using AcroFields,
AcroFields form = pdfReader.AcroFields;

but form is empty and has no keys or values. I don't think my PDF has data encoded as forms.

Comment: I've written my own extraction strategy now, and it's populating a class I've made 
     public class TextBoxPos
      {
      public float xstart;
      public float xend;
      public float ystart;
      public float yend;
      public StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();                
     }

But PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage only returns a string. How can I modify this to return something other than a string? I want to return the text as well as the co-ordinates..